# How do I use the first child of a list with createTextNode()

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, createtextnode

I'm trying to use js to print the first child of my list using createTextNode() and create an h1. I want my sentence to read "Blue? Great Colour." However, my sentence is reading [object] [object]? Great Colour. How do I correctly use the first child of my list?
https://jsfiddle.net/6x9a6rqv/

html:

```
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.list li:first-child {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

JS:

```
var colour = $('.list li:first-child')

var headerone = document.createElement("H1");
var t = document.createTextNode(colour + '? Great Colour.');
headerone.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(headerone);
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

In `colour` variable you have a reference to the DOM object. To get its text, use `text()` method:

```
document.createTextNode(colour.text() + '? Great Colour.')
```